# How to insert a value into a specific row of sqflite data table in flutter

Tags: database, flutter, dart, datatable, sqflite

How to insert a value into a specific row of `sqflite` data table in flutter ? I can insert values with this code but I need to insert values into a specific row.

```
Future<int> insert(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.insert(table, row,
        conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
  }
```

I used `ConflictAlgorithm` but it is not working.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: No. But I want to insert value into a specific row. This code can not do it.

Comment: If I understand correctly if you run await db.query(table, where: "id = ?", whereArgs: row[id],); after your code it doesn't return the same map row?

Comment: I don't need query. I need insert.